# Disable Open Cart 3 check out on sundays

Tags: php, opencart-3

I have a store which is set up with Open Cart 3. I want to disable the checkout on Sundays. I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

I added the code to following file cataloge/controller/checkout/checkput.php

```
class ControllerCheckoutCheckout extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Validate cart has products and has stock.
        if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
        }
        
        if (date("l") == "Sunday") {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            $this->session->data['error'] = 'Sorry we are closed on Sundays';
        }
```

Here is the full code before I added my line;

```
<?php

class ControllerCheckoutCheckout extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Validate cart has products and has stock.
        if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
        }
        
        
        // Validate minimum quantity requirements.
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product_total = 0;

            foreach ($products as $product_2) {
                if ($product_2['product_id'] == $product['product_id']) {
                    $product_total += $product_2['quantity'];
                }
            }

            if ($product['minimum'] > $product_total) {
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            }
        }

        $this->load->language('checkout/checkout');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment.min.js');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');

        // Required by klarna
        if ($this->config->get('payment_klarna_account') || $this->config->get('payment_klarna_invoice')) {
            $this->document->addScript('http://cdn.klarna.com/public/kitt/toc/v1.0/js/klarna.terms.min.js');
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_cart'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/cart')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true)
        );

        $data['text_checkout_option'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_option'), 1);
        $data['text_checkout_account'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_account'), 2);
        $data['text_checkout_payment_address'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_payment_address'), 2);
        $data['text_checkout_shipping_address'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_shipping_address'), 3);
        $data['text_checkout_shipping_method'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_shipping_method'), 4);
        
        if ($this->cart->hasShipping()) {
            $data['text_checkout_payment_method'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_payment_method'), 5);
            $data['text_checkout_confirm'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_confirm'), 6);
        } else {
            $data['text_checkout_payment_method'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_payment_method'), 3);
            $data['text_checkout_confirm'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_checkout_confirm'), 4); 
        }
        
        if (isset($this->session->data['error'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->session->data['error'];
            unset($this->session->data['error']);
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();

        if (isset($this->session->data['account'])) {
            $data['account'] = $this->session->data['account'];
        } else {
            $data['account'] = '';
        }

        $data['shipping_required'] = $this->cart->hasShipping();

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('checkout/checkout', $data));
    }

    public function country() {
        $json = array();

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');

        $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->get['country_id']);

        if ($country_info) {
            $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

            $json = array(
                'country_id'        => $country_info['country_id'],
                'name'              => $country_info['name'],
                'iso_code_2'        => $country_info['iso_code_2'],
                'iso_code_3'        => $country_info['iso_code_3'],
                'address_format'    => $country_info['address_format'],
                'postcode_required' => $country_info['postcode_required'],
                'zone'              => $this->model_localisation_zone->getZonesByCountryId($this->request->get['country_id']),
                'status'            => $country_info['status']
            );
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }

    public function customfield() {
        $json = array();

        $this->load->model('account/custom_field');

        // Customer Group
        if (isset($this->request->get['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($this->request->get['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $this->request->get['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }

        $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);

        foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
            $json[] = array(
                'custom_field_id' => $custom_field['custom_field_id'],
                'required'        => $custom_field['required']
            );
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
  }
```

Could anyone have any idea why this doesn't work or another way of disabling the checkout on Sundays?

Comment: it depends in which place of code you have added this. Which line? After what?

Comment: I have edited the post and you can now see where the code is added. This from the begining of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put this line below befoe the redirection, the error message will show up.

```
$this->session->data['error'] = 'Sorry we are closed on Sundays';
```

here is code after the change

```
    class ControllerCheckoutCheckout extends Controller {
        public function index() {
            // Validate cart has products and has stock.
            if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            }
    
            if (date("l") == "Sunday") {
                $this->session->data['error'] = 'Sorry we are closed on Sundays';
                $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
            }
```

[image: result]